# Why visible light satisfies Maxwell equations?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, maxwell-equations

As it is described in standard textbooks I looked at, the Maxwell equations were first established for electromagnetic fields created by electric currents. Then it is stated that it was discovered experimentally (by Kohlrausch and Weber) that the electric constant in these equations equals the speed of light. From that it is concluded that the visible light is a special case of electromagnetic field.  Thus it satisfies the Maxwell equations.

> Unless I miss something, it seems to me that the last conclusion is a too strong conclusion of the fact of coincidence of the speeds of propagation of light and of EM wave. Is there a more direct verification that the visible light satisfies the Maxwell equations?

Comment: Lots of questions like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145330/) one exist on this site, but very few of them seem to have good answers...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the experimental evidence that light is an electromagnetic wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145330/)

Comment: @AlmostClueless : This question is very similar to mine.  But I am not quite convinced by the answers there.

Comment: The evidence is absolutely overwhelming, I'm not even sure where to start. Maxwell's equations are an extremely accurate description of light from the galactic scale down to the subatomic scale, with discrepancies only existing at very very high energies due to Electro-Weak corrections.  Simply put, for all practical applications there are no known departures from Maxwell's laws.

Comment: @AfterShave : At the moment I would be happy with a reference to a discussion of simplest experiments with visible light confirming that it satisfies Maxwell equations.

Comment: Search for attosecond streaking. There they measure the E-field of a near-infrared light beam...its at the edge of the visible (it is still deep red though, you can see it). I think that your problem is that you are associating what a physical model means, and what reality really is. You need to see that Maxwell eqs are a model of reality, and so far everything fits perfectly well into Maxwell eqs, from refractive index, to the propagation and phase differences, plasma and its interaction with EM waves etc. But you want to **know** that that is the reality. Well, it is just a model and it fits

Comment: You’re going to want to look in the optics section of an EM textbook, maybe Griffiths.

Comment: Simple experiments that directly demonstrate that light is an electromagnetic wave consistent with Maxwell's equations may not be so simple. Visible light has wavelengths ranging from around 400 to 700 nanometres and hence a frequency range of roughly 430 to 750 terahertz.

Comment: here is a paper where they measure the E field again via a different method [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphoton.2015.269)

Answer (score 0):

The propagation of light itself is a good example, because it is consistent with Maxwell's equations. Not only in vacuum, but also in any medium with any boundary conditions. You can see wave guides like metal tubes of optical fibers.

In fact, refraction can also be explained with MAxwell equations...

But if this doesn't satisfy you, as it can be like that without being an electromagnetic field, **check that there are many electro-optic and magneto-optic effects**, such as Kerr effect, Pockels effect, Faraday effect...